# argparse subparsers with functions

Tags: python, argparse

Hello I am starting with `argparse`. My goal is to build a CLI with main commands that accept arguments and redirect to the corresponding commands functions. Here is what I did so far:

```
def main():

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    subparsers = parser.add_subparsers()

    command1_parser = subparsers.add_parser('command1')
    command1_parser.set_defaults(func=command1)
    command1_parser.add_argument('--name', dest='name')

    command2_parser = subparsers.add_parser('command2')
    command2_parser.set_defaults(func=command2)
    command2_parser.add_argument('--frequency', dest='frequency')

    args = parser.parse_args()

def command1():

    # do something with args.name

def command2():

    # do something with args.frequency

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

When I do:

```
entrypoint command1 --name Hello
```

Or:

```
entrypoint command2 --frequency 10
```

It fails to catch the corresponding `args`. What I am doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Look at the **full** `subparsers` `set_defaults` example in the docs.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Because you need to invoke the function manually by `args.func(args)`:

```
import argparse

def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    subparsers = parser.add_subparsers()

    command1_parser = subparsers.add_parser('command1')
    command1_parser.set_defaults(func=command1)
    command1_parser.add_argument('--name', dest='name')

    command2_parser = subparsers.add_parser('command2')
    command2_parser.set_defaults(func=command2)
    command2_parser.add_argument('--frequency', dest='frequency')

    args = parser.parse_args()
    args.func(args)

def command1(args):
    print("command1: %s" % args.name)

def command2(args):
    print("comamnd2: %s" % args.frequency)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: This throws the error `AttributeError: 'Namespace' object has no attribute 'func'` at the line `args.func(args)` if the program is run without any arguments.

Comment: @FilipS. right. This is just the minimal change to make the OP's code to work. Whoever use this code should add relevant sanitation checks.

Comment: You can add a `required=True` to `subparsers = parser.add_subparsers()` to have argparse run the check for you.